# Map various words that similar pronunciation during search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there anyway  i can map different terms like "karnatic" , "carnatic" during search. That is when i search for carnatic, all the documents having the word karnatic should also match.
This is not synonym based search but then using synonym set here might not work everytime. I feel some algorithm might do a better job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonetic analysis is what you are looking for.
You can find it [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic)
It is capable of variant mapping words having similar pronunciation together. As it is algorithmic based , it gives a good results